# Error when export Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar, export

[image]

How can I fix this problem>>>>>> ???
File >> Export >> Java >> Runnable JAR file 
but  it doesn't work for me

I changed the library but it's still

Comment: The picture is so small, I can't read anything

Comment: @ThomasWeller the picture is readable if you use your browser's zoom in (ctrl +).

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525711) of Eclipse Oxygen.1a which has already been fixed. Just update to Oxygen.2 (_Help > Check for Updates_).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your project. Chances are it's a small bug in the updating of the project.

1. Try running the project and then exporting.
2. Try restarting eclipse then exporting.